# Aos animation does not work when i refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, animation

I'm working on a react.js project.Aos animation does not work when i refresh the page.It works when I open another page and come back.

```
import 'aos/dist/aos.css';
import AOS from 'aos';


function MenuCard(props) {
  AOS.init();
  AOS.refresh();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <div class="card bg-dark text-white" id="cardBody" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-duration="800">

            <img src={photos[`${props.id}`]} id="image" class="card-img" alt="..." />
            <div class="card-img-overlay" id="cardImg">
              <div id="baslik">
                <a class="card-title" href={`#${props.title}`} id="cardTitle">{props.title}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue with this code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    setTimeout(function() { AOS.refresh(); }, 500);
});
```

it refreshes AOS after 0.5 seconds.